# Prevent copy of class instance when importing in two different files - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a class like this: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-wv4c0s?file=/security.js)
(In the sandbox, I have imported file1 so that that part of code gets executed first and then trying to access the same using file2 however it returns undefined)

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
const deleteMillis = 3600 * 1000;
class Security {
    activeSessions: Record<string, { ua: string }>;
    constructor() {
        this.activeSessions = {};
    }
    getSession(session: string, ua: string): { ua: string } | undefined {
        const currentSession = this.activeSessions[session];
        console.log(this.activeSessions, this.activeSessions[session], session);
        if (!currentSession) return;
        if (ua !== currentSession.ua) return;
        return currentSession;
    }
    addSession(ua: string): string {
        const session = crypto.randomUUID();
        this.activeSessions[session] = {
            ua
        };
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.removeSession(session);
        }, deleteMillis);
        return session;
    }
    removeSession(session: string) {
        delete this.activeSessions[session];
    }
}

const security = new Security();
export default security;
```

I want to use `security` instance of this class into multiple es module files. Let's say file1.js and file2.js.

Now the problem is that when i do an import:

import security from "@/security"; // file-1
import security from "@/security"; // file-2

The problem with the above is that the data doesn't remain synced in both the files and they operate independently.

these two files create two different instances however I wanted to use one instance in both the files. How can I achieve the same? Do I need to create a third file or what exactly should be the approach?

As suggested in the answer, I tried this:

```
class Security {
    activeSessions: Record<string, { ua: string }>;
    private static instance: Security;
    constructor() {
        this.activeSessions = {};
    }
    getSession(session: string, ua: string): { ua: string } | undefined {
        const currentSession = this.activeSessions[session];
        console.log(this.activeSessions, this.activeSessions[session], session);
        if (!currentSession) return;
        if (ua !== currentSession.ua) return;
        return currentSession;
    }
    addSession(ua: string): string {
        const session = crypto.randomUUID();
        this.activeSessions[session] = {
            ua
        };
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.removeSession(session);
        }, deleteMillis);
        return session;
    }
    removeSession(session: string) {
        delete this.activeSessions[session];
    }
    static getInstance(): Security {
        if (!Security.instance) {
            Security.instance = new Security();
        }
        console.log('Security instance', Security.instance);
        return Security.instance;
    }
}

const security = Security.getInstance();
export default security;
```

However this also fails to preserve the instance.

Comment: The code looks like TypeScript. Maybe your setup that converts your files to JavaScript is incorrect.

Comment: I converted it to javascript as well. Still not working: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-wv4c0s?file=/security.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach, we define a static method getInstance in the Security class and call it to get Security instance in other files

```js
class Security {
    private static instance: Security;
    
    // other methods and variables

    static getInstance(): Security {
        if (!Security.instance) {
            Security.instance = new Security();
        }
        return Security.instance;
    }
}

export default Security;
```

Usage example

```js
let securityInstance = Security.getInstance();
securityInstance.getSession();
```

This is called the Singleton design pattern, you can read more about it here [Singleton design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton)

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work. It still produces two instances. I have updated the edit in answer. Can you cross check once?

Comment: The reason is the same, when es module import happens, the same file gets re-run and hence two instances gets created

Comment: You just have to export the Security class from the file. `export default Security`

Answer (score 1):

The shown code works for me (the session object is the same for both files). It is, however, not clear what you want to achieve with the code.

In `file1.js` you have `security.addSession("abc", "deg")` in `file2.js` you have `security.getSession("abc", "def")`. (`deg` vs `def`).

After calling `security.addSession("abc", "deg")` the contents of `this.activeSessions['abc']` is: `{ua : "deg"}`.

When you call `security.getSession("abc", "def")` you have the test `if (ua !== currentSession.ua) return;` which compares `ua` which is `def` with `currentSession.ua` which is `deg` and that is not equal, so you return `undefined`.